# Angular CSS Layout applying but without results

Tags: css, angular10

I did simple grid but it is looks like styles is applying but grid is not working correct. All grid items have wrong width and height but css is applied. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dqhcwr) Why is that? How to fix that?

**app.component.html**

```
<header>Header</header>
<nav>Nav</nav>
<main>
  <section>Intro</section>
  <article>Cake</article>
  <article>Cake</article>
  <article>Cake</article>
</main>
<aside>Aside</aside>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

**app.component.css**

```
.grid-item,
header,
main,
nav,
aside,
footer{
background: #044BD9;
color: white;
border: 1px solid #377EFF;
}

header{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 4;
}
footer{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 4;
}
```

**styles.css**

```
*{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body{
    background: #07038C ;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 15em auto 15em;
    grid-template-rows: min-content auto min-content;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "CSS is applied"? I see no custom styles on the article elements in that demo.

Comment: @Paulie_D, when you will do the same thing in Angular component it would place all items in one column, ignoring 'grid-column-start:' , 'grid-column-end:'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the component comes in a wrapper `<my-app _nghost-mfj-c40="" ng-version="10.0.9">` which does not have `display:grid`. I'd suggest `body > *` instead of just `body`...?

```css
.grid-item,
header,
main,
nav,
aside,
footer {
  background: #044BD9;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #377EFF;
}

header {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

footer {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background: #07038C;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body>* {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15em auto 15em;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto min-content;
}
```

```html
<my-app>
  <header>Header</header>
  <nav>Nav</nav>
  <main>
    <section>Intro</section>
    <article>Cake</article>
    <article>Cake</article>
    <article>Cake</article>
  </main>
  <aside>Aside</aside>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</my-app>
```